# How to completely execute a function without jumping to another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have function to set the nav bar using `ng-if` that's first to be executed.In that when reaches `Promise.all` it jumps out to another function so the DOM is already created without check `ng-if` values.I need to execute that function without jumps to another,completely.How to get this.Here I have tried it:

```
$scope.GetNavigationMenu = function GetNavigationMenu() {
        var modules = ["Dashboard", "Requirements", "Deviation Report", "Schedule", "Permission"];
        Promise.all(modules.map(Module => httpService.get(serviceBase + rightsPermissionUrl, { Module })))
          .then((list) => {
              // do stuff with `list` array
              $scope.navigationMenu = list;
          });
    }
```

Comment: put all the logic you want to be executed sequentially in the `then` of `Promise.all`

Comment: Yes.It's take a while to return but In the mean time goes out of function.How to get stay back there in the same function?

Comment: Ajax requests (promises) does not work like you want. Put all logic that is related to be executed after promise to `.then`

Comment: I only needs the value for $scope.navigationMenu there is no code there.@AseemUpadhyay How to make stay back until get request completes?

Comment: Can you please modify my code as an answer please?

Comment: `return` the promise from the function and make the caller also wait for it.

Answer (score 1):

you can make your function an async function and await for the resposnse like below:

```
$scope.GetNavigationMenu = async function GetNavigationMenu() {
    var modules = ["Dashboard", "Requirements", "Deviation Report", "Schedule", "Permission"];
    let list = await Promise.all(modules.map(Module => httpService.get(serviceBase + rightsPermissionUrl, { Module })));
    // do stuff with `list` array
    $scope.navigationMenu = list;

}
```

Also you do not need to define function name again => 
$scope.GetNavigationMenu = function(){} 
will work 
[MDN reference for async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: This won't change anything unless the caller already knows how to work with promises. In which case the `async`/`await` is unneccessary, a simple `return` would suffice.